# javascript simple math issue

Tags: javascript, math, subtraction

I have a simple math problem in javascript that I can't solve.

```
var prodajna_avg = parseFloat(vpc - (vpc * (rab_avg / 100))).toFixed(2);
var nabavna = parseFloat(<?php echo "$nabavna_cijena"; ?>);
document.getElementById("brutto_avg").textContent = parseFloat(prodajna_avg - nabavna);
```

Problem is in line three. I don't get the correct amount and I don't know why. In first row amount is 5.624,17 and second row is 3.904,54. Third row is returning 5.620,19 for some reason, while it should be 1.719,63.

Can you help me? I'm learning javascript that's why it's a problem for me.

Thanks.

Comment: `toFixed` function converts number into a string, so that may be the cause.

Comment: What happens if you change the row amounts to "5,624.17" and "3,904.54"? Maybe it's confused about what decimal separator to use.

Comment: [Works fine for me](https://jsfiddle.net/skhrqp2v/2/).  Something else must be going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that `$nabavna_cijena` is correctly formatted.

```
var nabavna = parseFloat("3.904,54");  // --> nabavna == 3.904
var nabavna = parseFloat("3,904.54");  // --> nabavna == 3
var nabavna = parseFloat("3904.54");   // --> nabavna == 3904.54
```

The function `parseFloat()` requires that the decimal point is `.` and it does not allow a group separator.

Comment: This was the problem! Thank you very much!